# Why $\langle I, J\rangle =R$ for distinct prime ideals $I$, $J$ of a principal ideal domain $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain with identity and $I$, $J$ be distinct prime ideals of $R$. Prove that $1 \in \langle I, J\rangle$ hence $\langle I, J\rangle = R$. How to prove?

Comment: in general if $R$ is a ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$ so if $1\in I$ we have $I=R$!!

Comment: You need the extra side condition $I,J \neq 0$!

Comment: No @JohannesKloos, he needs not.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Think of maximality (why does prime imply maximality in a PID?)

Answer (score 0):

Without words:

$$1\in\langle I,J\rangle\implies\;\exists\,i\in I\,,\,j\in J\;\;s.t.\;\; i+j=1\implies$$

$$\forall\,x\in R\;,\;\;x=x\cdot1=x(i+j)=xi+xj\in\langle I,J\rangle$$

Comment: The point was to prove that $1$ was in the ideal $\langle I,J\rangle$, not that if $1$ is in the ideal than it is the whole ring.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I=\langle p\rangle$ and $J=\langle q\rangle$ be two distinct prime ideals in the PID $R$. Therefore neither $p\mid q$ nor $q\mid p$.

Consider the ideal $\langle I,J\rangle=\langle c\rangle$. Since $p,q\in\langle c\rangle$ we have $c\mid p,q$, and since primes are irreducible, then either $c$ is $p$ times a unit (which is impossible since it would imply $p\mid q$), or $q$ times a unit (which is also impossible) or a unit itself, and therefore $\langle c\rangle=R$.